# Match recursive pattern without recursion

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently working on a simple markup parser. After my first attempt was quite prone to errors I decided to give regular expressions a shot and learnt the syntax. So far so good, I got a pattern that matches my markup.

But just of now I realized that I have a situation where I got recursion. I'm new to regex and thus don't know how to solve this without recursion (which sadly isn't available in C#).

As a brief explanation, I've got the following markup scheme:

**{TagName}...Content...{/TagName}** are inline markups which are used for text formatting (bold, underline or more complex types like mail links).

Like all markup they can have parameters. This works so far.

The second type are value markups which generate dynamic text during parsing:

**[TagName|ParameterName:ParameterValue;...:...;...]**

My current expression matches them. Parameters have their own expression pattern which is resolved at a later stage on-demand (working fine).

```
\[([^\|]+)\|(?<Parameters>[^\]]+)\]
```

What troubles me now is that I need to have nested markups. Means, that parameter values of markups can be markups as well, like in this example:

```
[PS|Data:SetToken;default:Token.SetToken([PS|Data:ClassRef], ref [PS|Data:InstanceFieldName])]
```

The problem now is that my expression from above only matches until the closing bracket of the first nested markup, thus ending it to early and breaking the parsing procedure.

I figure that with recursion I could easily match the nested ones as well, as of now I just need that the match actually matches until the right closing bracket.

I've seen that I got the same problem with my inline markups (but usually you don't use the same twice, still an issue though).

I've read that there is some kind of regex feature that matches an equivalent count of characters to some others, like "aaabbb". Could this fix it? Any other solutions?

Comment: Maybe the [balancing feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) is useful for your task. [See demo at regex storm](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b(%3f%3e%5c%5b(%3f%3cc%3e)%7c%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%5c%5d(%3f%3c-c%3e))*(%3f(c)(%3f!))%5c%5d&i=%5bbarbar%5d%5bPS%7cData%3aSetToken%3bdefault%3aToken.SetToken(%5bPS%7cData%3aClassRef%5d%2c+ref+%5bPS%7cData%3aInstanceFieldName%5d)%5d+bar+%5bfoo%5bfoo%5d%5d).

Comment: I think that is what I've seen earlier. I'll give it a shot, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, try something like [`\[PS(?>\[(?<c>)|[^][]+|\](?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\]`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5bPS(%3f%3e%5c%5b(%3f%3cc%3e)%7c%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%5c%5d(%3f%3c-c%3e))*(%3f(c)(%3f!))%5c%5d&i=%5bbarbar%5d%5bPS%7cData%3aSetToken%3bdefault%3aToken.SetToken(%5bPS%7cData%3aClassRef%5d%2c+ref+%5bPS%7cData%3aInstanceFieldName%5d)%5d+bar+%5bfoo%5bfoo%5d%5d) you're welcome.

Comment: That's really close! I extended it about a named group: `\[(?<Tag>[^\|]+)(?>\[(?<c>)|[^][]+|\](?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\]` because the tag name is not static and I need to fetch that one. Now I would just need to get the parameters as group as well. It does match the right part, but is there a way of capturing the content behind "|"? I tried to extend it but frankly your expression is a bit too high for me, can't really interpret it ...

Comment: Try [`\[(?<Tag>[^][|]*)(?>\[(?<c>)|[^][]+|\](?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\]`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b(%3f%3cTag%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%7c%5d*)(%3f%3e%5c%5b(%3f%3cc%3e)%7c%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%5c%5d(%3f%3c-c%3e))*(%3f(c)(%3f!))%5c%5d&i=%5bbarbar%5d%5bPS%7cData%3aSetToken%3bdefault%3aToken.SetToken(%5bPS%7cData%3aClassRef%5d%2c+ref+%5bPS%7cData%3aInstanceFieldName%5d)%5d+bar+%5bfoo%5bfoo%5d%5d) as the `[^\|]` would skip brackets. Moment for content behind `|`

Comment: [`\[(?<Tag>[^][|]*)(?:\|(?<Param>[^][|(]*))?(?>\[(?<c>)|[^][]+|\](?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\]`](http://goo.gl/jBE2C2) like this? I don't know what's exact requirement and don't understand it anymore. You play with it and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Almost. Now it is still skipping the nested ones in the 'Param' group. It only goes to "SetToken(" but not any further :-/

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you were looking for...

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("[PS|Data:SetToken;default:Token.SetToken([PS|Data:ClassRef], ref [PS|Data:InstanceFieldName])]",@"\[([^\|]+)\|(?<Parameters>[^\]]+)\]",RegexOptions.Multiline)
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(match => new 
                   {
                       First = match.Groups[1].Value,
                       Second = match.Groups[2].Value
                   });
```

[image: Regex Output]

Comment: Not exactly. It should match the whole string basically. Ignoring the two which are nested, as these will be in group 2 (parameters) and thus procesed separately later with another regex. The problem is that it only matches to the first "]" found, which is the one of the first nested markup, but not the actual closing bracket of the first opening bracket. Like I said: Would be recursive actually :-/

Comment: I get what you mean... you can probably do it but it wont be pretty, ill have a quick shot

Comment: What a bummer if I using regex turns out to be senseless because of that ... Then I'll probably have to roll-back to my old approach and fix that one. But thanks, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeah... I give up, I'll probably pick it back up later because I know its possible... It's just a chicken and egg problem... [After attempting a few times...](http://tclhost.com/Mr43CET.gif)

Comment: As booble bubble has mentioned in the comment on my question, the balancing groups could be of help. I'll try it by myself for practise, so you either wait for my results or you try it as well. Just letting you know in case I can solve it by myself ;)

Comment: If you do solve it... warn me in the comment, I definitely wanna give this a shot in a few hours when I get back home :)

Comment: Found not really a working solution. It worked for inline markups but not for value markups. Booble Bubble already delivered quite a good approach, though it does not group the whole parameters (skips again once it hits a nested one) but it does match to the right bracket. I'll try around but any help is appreciated as it get's a little to complicated for my skills :-/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this article on [retkomma](https://retkomma.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/nested-regular-expressions-explained/) I found the solution. It's a lot easier than thought. My personal problem was that I kinda misunderstood matching groups. And after all I missed the knowledge about how to invalidate the matching progress if there's an uneven count. The article really helped therefore.

Here's the pattern for my value markups:

```
(?<!\\)\[
(?'Tag'[^|]*)
(\|
(?'Parameters'
(?>
\[(?'A')|\](?'-A')|.?
)*
)
)?
(?(A)(?!))
(?<!\\)\]
```

This pattern matches the right parts, saves the right groups and furthermore allows to escape '[' or ']' thus making them invalid matches (in case you need to write that without marking any markup).

I'm still trying to get the inline markup regex pattern working. It actually does work already, though in some rare cases (when nested one's have the same tag name) it still doesn't work. But the initial question is answered.